# Is there a way to access cell tower information without having to activate GPS?

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, location

I am quite new to Android development, but I was wondering if there is a possibility to get a general location through cell tower information without having to activate the GPS on the phone. Shouldn't the phone be able to access cell towers without GPS?

I have tried using TelephonyManager and the method allCellInfo(), but it needs the fine location permission which in turn means that I have to activate GPS. However, I thought the coarse location permission should be enough in this case because I only want access to cell tower info and not GPS. The returned list from allCellInfo() is always empty, unless I activate GPS which makes sense because the method requires the fine location permission. I just don't understand why this is the case when as far as I understood the coarse location permission should be enough for cell tower info (and wifi).

Is there any other method/class/package/library that can help with that? Is it even possible at all to access cell tower info without having GPS turned on? Maybe something that only uses the coarse location permission?

Comment: `The standard way to get location doesn't require GPS to be turned on.` ??? @Tenfour04. The standard way to get location is using GPS.

Comment: Course location can be obtained without GPS if wifi or cell network are turned on.

Comment: Can be but the standard way to get location is using GPS.

Comment: I haven't done this in years, but when I did it in native Android code, you didn't specify what sensors were used. You just got location updates. If GPS happened to be on, they'd be more accurate. Now it looks like the standard way is to use Google Play Services, which also doesn't have you specify GPS, but rather a desired accuracy: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int) The "standard way" is to obtain the location through any sources available, GPS or not.

Comment: Then how does it work? I am probably missing some info, but how would you access cell info? With something other than TelephonyManager.allCellInfo()? Because with this it only seems to work with GPS

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want. Your question sounds like you are only interested in location, but you keep mentioning cell info. Do you need something other than location?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you want is to try and figure out location without asking for any location permissions.  And no, Android isn't going to let you do that.  Or at least, not through anything as obvious as cell tower info (which they use in their coarse location determination).

If you just want to avoid GPS (for example for battery reasons), ask for coarse location permission.  This will not turn on GPS, but will use network info to get a location.  This will allow you to skip all the signal strength math yourself (which frankly you're not going to do as well as they do, since they have a LOT more info on locations of networks than you do).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for [the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` from `LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/LocationManager#network_provider). Quoting the docs, "If present, this provider determines location based on nearby of cell tower and WiFi access points".